# Allocate uninitialized slice

Tags: optimization, initialization, go

Is there some way to allocate an uninitialized [slice](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_types) in Go? A frequent pattern is to create a slice of a given size as a buffer, and then only use part of it to [receive](http://golang.org/pkg/net/#Conn) data. For example:

```
b := make([]byte, 0x20000) // b is zero initialized
n, err := conn.Read(b)
// do stuff with b[:n]. all of b is zeroed for no reason
```

This initialization can add up when lots of buffers are being allocated, as the [spec](http://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value) states it will default initialize the array on allocation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get *non zeroed* byte buffers from [bufs.Cache.Get](http://godoc.org/github.com/cznic/bufs#Cache.Get) (or see `CCache` for the concurrent safe version). From the [docs](http://godoc.org/github.com/cznic/bufs):

> NOTE: The buffer returned by Get *is not guaranteed* to be zeroed. That's okay for e.g. passing a buffer to io.Reader. If you need a zeroed buffer use Cget.

Answer (score 0):

Technically you could by allocating the memory outside the go runtime and using `unsafe.Pointer`, but this is definitely the wrong thing to do.

A better solution is to reduce the number of allocations. Move buffers outside loops, or, if you need per goroutine buffers, allocate several of them in a pool and only allocate more when they're needed.

```
type BufferPool struct {
    Capacity int
    buffersize int
    buffers []byte
    lock sync.Mutex
}

func NewBufferPool(buffersize int, cap int) {
    ret := new(BufferPool)
    ret.Capacity = cap
    ret.buffersize = buffersize
    return ret
}

func (b *BufferPool) Alloc() []byte {
    b.lock.Lock()
    defer b.lock.Unlock()
    if len(b.buffers) == 0 {
        return make([]byte, b.buffersize)
    } else {
        ret := b.buffers[len(b.buffers) - 1]
        b.buffers = b.buffers[0:len(b.buffers) - 1]
        return ret
    }
}

func (b *BufferPool) Free(buf []byte) {
    if len(buf) != b.buffersize {
        panic("illegal free")
    }
    b.lock.Lock()
    defer b.lock.Unlock()
    if len(b.buffers) < b.Capacity {
        b.buffers = append(b.buffers, buf)
    }
}
```

Comment: Also note that in the example, forgetting to call Free on a buffer causes it to just get garbage collected and not added back to the pool, it doesn't leak.

Comment: Should you be using a buffered channel to store your freed buffers?

Comment: @MattJoiner You could do that instead, but you'd still need a lock to safely check how many items are buffered, so then you're just locking twice, or not check the length but you'll leak goroutines as you'll always have (peak_use - capacity) goroutines waiting to push onto the channel.

Comment: No, why wouldn't you push and not block? Put a default clause in a select if the buffer is full, and give up if that's the case.

Comment: @MattJoiner Oh right that would work too. But I still don't think it matters much either way which you use. And it's just example code, the locks are a little more straightforward IMO, but the concept is the exact same, a queue of pre-allocated slices.